# How do I convert a java project to C# in eclipse using Sharpen?

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, sharpen-tool

I have checked out sharpen from svn, and tried following the following directions:

http://developer.db4o.com/Blogs/Product/tabid/167/entryid/95/Default.aspx

I installed sharpen as a plugin per the instructions.  However, then the article starts talking about ant scripts and that's where I get lost.  I'm not experienced with eclipse, can anyone shed some light on how I'm supposed to use the sharpen plugin to convert my java project to c#?

*** UPDATE

Ok, may have figured it out. This link describes how to setup an ant build script and run it:

http://individual.utoronto.ca/kia/

I also had to download Nant.

Comment: feel free to add an answer to your own question and mark it as the correct answer. That way if someone searches StackOverFlow and your question comes up in the results they can easily see that it has an answer.

Comment: So how to invoke Sharpen after I installed it?